# What is the difference between Dr. Robotnik and Eggman?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog-series

Are they the same, or alter egos? Does ["Eggman"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Eggman) refer to a specific persona with unique characteristics compared to "Dr. Robotnik"? Does the name change based on between the 3D/2D game perspective, or the game's region (Japan vs. US)? Does he ever assert a name preference, and does he accept or reject the Eggman nickname? They look the same—is there a reason why the Sonic series uses both names simultaneously?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are different names for the same character. The Wikipedia article you linked has the explanation, sourced from the former head of Sonic Team, [Yuji Naka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuji_Naka):

> "Robotnik" is the character's real name while "Eggman" is a "common name taken after his shape."

In various iterations of the franchise, they've chosen different names for him, with Robotnik being more of the English name, and Eggman the Japanese.  However, since [Sonic Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_Adventure) (1999) he tends to go by Doctor Eggman in both English and Japanese translations of his video game appearances.

As far as whether or not this is a preference, a teasing nickname, or just a localization hiccup, the character rarely remarks about his different names or his own preferences.  However, as Jupotter [points out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64791/what-is-the-difference-between-dr-robotnik-and-eggman#comment91165_64793), in Sonic Generations, Classic Tails refers to him as Dr. Robotnik, and he comments that nobody calls him that anymore.  This would seem to indicate that he's at least aware of his different names.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single game where he's called Robotnik after SA 2. And Robotnik was such an awesome name! Also, IIRC, Eggman was a nickname in SA 1 (which he didn't accept) and he assumed it as his own name from SA 2 on, but it's been a while since I played

Comment: He was also referred to as Dr. Robotnik in the animated series!

Comment: AFAIK Eggman was the original JP name while Robotnik was the original ENG name. *"The English instruction manual for his 1991 debut game Sonic the Hedgehog described the character's full name as "Doctor Ivo Robotnik"[3] while the original Japanese version's instruction manual for the same game called him "Doctor Eggman"."*

Comment: There is also the scene from Sonic Generation where young Tails call him Dr Robotnik, and he answer that nobody call him that anymore.

Comment: @Jupotter, added that to the answer.  I was pretty sure there was at least one time when they brought it up, but man, I could not remember where or when :)

Comment: @Pubby is correct. To this end, the unification of both names into the same character in the game continuity was only in place as of the Dreamcast era (SA/SA2). There have been a number of... "inconsistencies", but otherwise he now usually refers to himself as Dr. Eggman in the games while the comics continue to call him Dr. Ivo Robotnik.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Although I'm not 100% sure anymore, I thought he was still called Robotnik in Sega Allstars Smash (the tennis game for Wii).

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of showing my age, geekiness, and awesome memory...

Just before, or  just as *Sonic The Hedgehog* was being released on the Megadrive, a publication called *Mean Machines* (UK) had a pull out comic (Sonic The Comic didn't appear for a couple of years after that).

[image: Mean Machines Special Edition Sonic The Hedgehog cover]

In this pull out comic, Sonic starts out as being brown, and cobalt in a treadmill explosion turns him blue. Why there's cobalt involved in a treadmill, I have no idea. In the same explosion Doctor Kintobor turns evil for some unexplained reason. It was a really flaky story.

So, becoming his polar opposite in a flaky story, Kintobor became Robotnik (much like the Kaleds became Daleks, for all of you Whovians out there).

After typing "Kintobor" into a search engine, I have found this image:

[image: Kintobor and Sonic]

So, based on that: his name is Robotnik. Although, I suspect his original name was Eggman.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for the random initial caps on some words? It's making it hard to understand as I don't know which words are names and which are not...

Comment: I remember in the early 90s, this was the official backstory on Sega of America's website as well.

Comment: "Ovi" means "egg" in Latin(ish).

Answer (score 3):

Same Person different name. This name is Ivo Robotnik, he's called "Eggman" because of his shape. Really a nickname that's been with him since Sonic adventures.

I don't remember him having a preference or not liking the name "Eggman". He like some of the characters, does have alternate universe version of themselves. Like "Dr. Eggman Nega".

Answer (score 1):

Ivo Robotnik and Eggman are actually one and the same. Check [this link](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Eggman) for references.

Comment: Consider adding some details from the link you posted to the answer as a quote. If for any reason the link goes away this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 1):

They're actually different guys... who are the same guy:

- [Dr. Ivo Robotnik](http://archiesonic.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Ivo_Robotnik) is a nemesis of Sonic's.
- [Dr. Ivo "Eggman" Robotnik](http://archiesonic.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Eggman) is the alternate history version of the first Dr. Robotnik, who eventually crossed over to the main timeline to become a nemesis of Sonic's after the first one was finally defeated.

So, two different guys, but kind of also the same guy. But not.

Answer (score 0):

Doctor Eggman seems to be a nickname that both he and the characters around him have accepted and use frequently.

However, Robotnik is his given surname.

In both the Japanese and American version of Sonic Adventure 2, Robotnik has a grandfather by the name of [Gerald Robotnik](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Gerald_Robotnik).

Answer (score 0):

It's the same idea as Princess Toadstool, vs. Princess Peach. In the west, Peach was essentially the name she was deemed with,  after the first few Mario games. Wheras in the West after some Sonic Games, people often called Robotnik, "Eggman" based on his shape.  I think it's an east vs. West thing.

Comment: "deemed with" - what do you mean here?

Answer (score -1):

In a latter episode of Sonic the Hedgehog, Robotnik stated that Eggman was his great-grandfather.

Eggman and Robotnik are two different people.

Comment: You may be confusing the story of Prof. Robotnik, Eggman's grandfather. Please include sources if you have them, for clarification.

Answer (score -2):

Robotnik is his real name I think that they call him Dr.Eggman is because of his oval belly but I don't get why Tails still calls him Robotnik.